# Modifying Cypher Query Engine

Tags: neo4j

I would like to modify the way Cypher processes queries sent to it for pattern matching. I have read about Execution plans and how Cypher chooses the best plan with the least number of operations and all. This is pretty good. However I am looking into implementing a Similarity Search feature that allows you to specify a Query graph that would be matched if not exact, close (similar). I have seen a few examples of this in theory. I would like to implement something of this sort for Neo4j. Which I am guessing would require a change in how the Query Engine deals with queries sent to it. Or Worse :)

Here are some links that demonstrate the idea

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dchau/graphite/graphite.pdf
http://www.cidrdb.org/cidr2013/Papers/CIDR13_Paper72.pdf

I am looking for ideas. Anything at all in relation to the topic would be helpful. Thanks in advance

(:I)<-[:NEEDING_HELP_FROM]-(:YOU)

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: What do I need to build something like this for neo4j?

Comment: Of course you can fork Neo4j on github and make your modifications to Cypher directly there - however this requires a lot of knowledge on the internal structures. I guess you're better off following @MicTech's advice below.

Comment: If you would agree with me, neo4j doesn't support similarity searches at the moment. I would like to hear your views

Comment: The only "non-exactness" in Cypher currently are `OPTIONAL MATCH` and variable path length matches, e.g. `(a)-[:REL*1..3]->(b)`.

Comment: The execution of Cypher I am guessing cannot be modified with a plugin. Because the main idea was to end up creating a new "keyword" for the Cypher Language that would enable this new functionality (Similarity Search). What are your views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my point of view, better for you is to create [Unmanaged Extensions](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html).

Because you can create you own custom functionality into Neo4j server.

You are not able to extend Cypher Language without your own fork of source code.

Comment: Wow! thats a big one. So you're saying its impossible to create a new Cypher keyword through unmanaged extensions? So how do you think I could go about the idea?